# Example use of ASSERT with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, assert

After reading [the documentation for ASSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSERT), I am still confused how to use it, and can't find any examples online of how I would do something simple using `ASSERT` in a .sql script.

For example, say I want to `ASSERT` that the number of rows returned from `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_col = 3` is equal to 10.

Can someone provide a working example of that?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would assume you try todo smth similar?

```
so=# select count(*) from pg_database;
 count
-------
    21
(1 row)

so=# do $$ begin assert (select count(*) from pg_database) = 21, 'not 21!';end;$$;
DO
so=# do $$ begin assert (select count(*) from pg_database) = 22, 'not 22!';end;$$;
ERROR:  not 22!
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 1 at ASSERT
```

Answer (score 4):

```
do $$
    begin
        ASSERT 1 = 2;
    end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But note, it works only starting from PostgreSql 9.5. In older versions you can define your own assert-function such like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION __assert(boolean) RETURNS VOID AS $$
    BEGIN
        IF NOT $1 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'ASSERTING FAILED';
        END IF;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And then use in this way

```
do $$
    declare
        tmp char;
    begin
        tmp := __assert(tmp_to_https('https') = 'https');
    end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```